# Object that looks like a circle, square and triangle in different cross sections?

Tags: math, geometry, puzzle

The object or shape must be circular in cross section one way, triangular in cross section from another direction and  square (or rectangular) in cross section from a third direction? any idea what this object might look like?

Answer (score 3):

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSjEQ.jpg

This is some filler because there are not enough characters to submit my answer.

Comment: Didn't Martin Gardner write a column about a design for a digital sundial?